# How to remove a grey shadow from a JPEG?

Tags: photoshop

So in Photoshop we all know it's relatively easy to remove a white background from a .jpg image if the contrast is quite visible.

The problem with this image though is it has a grey shadow at the bottom of the image that is reliant on the white background, and therefore once it becomes transparent the shadow looks nasty.

What would be the best approach to remove this once the white background had been removed?

Thanks

https://s15.postimg.org/k2itasu7v/i_Stock_104502239_LARGE.jpg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Polygonal Lasso Tool. Manual removing.
Zoom to the shadow, select it with the  Polygonal Lasso Tool > Right click and : Refine the edge + give it a bit of Feather and paint using the background color of the image.